# Help me on my Ubuntu-based distribution

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, chroot

I have everything set up for making my own Ubuntu-based distribution (custom desktop environment, wallpapers, themes, software, logos).

Here's what I have done so far:

1. I got a 14.04 ISO,
2. Extracted it to a directory in my home folder, then
3. unsquashfs'd /casper/filesystem.squashfs
4. I have already mounted --bind'ed /dev, /dev/pts, /dev/shm, /proc and /sys and have a fully-working chroot environment with internet connection and APT

I am ready to do everything. When I'm done, I will squashfs my remaster to /casper/filesystem.squashfs and mkisofs with my new Live distribution. But I want it to be installable to my hard disk, so my questions are as follows:

- Will the programs installed in the chroot be automatically installed on the hard disk at installation time (by ubiquity)?
- Will their settings/configuration files be kept?
- I know the Live system will be flawless, but what about the actual installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software installed into the chrooted version using either "apt-get" or "dpkg" will be installed.

Regarding configurations files:

- you can replace the dummy configuration file in the package you want to change, then repackage the software. That is the more difficult but also more appropriate method. But this does not work as well anymore since more and more packages tend to create their configuration during the {packagename}.postinst part of the installation so that became a lot more difficult.
- you can add user specific configuration files to "/etc/skel/". Files in there will be copied to your users home ("/etc/skel/Desktop/1.txt" would create a file "1.txt" on your desktop. "/etc/skel/.config/user-dirs.dirs
  " would contain the user defined directories (untested ;))). Settings for firefox, chrome, desktop can all be set to custom configurations. That is also the place to store .desktop files. You can also include a script here to copy configurations to other directories (samba, apache, mysql if those are your targets).